# value vs ng-value with json format

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-value

In the first snippet, when using ng-value directive, ng-value= to json, behave like an object, I can get the json format and use it like an object.
But, if I am using value attribute instead I can't use it like an obejct.
Why in the second snippet I can't display  {{selectedName.a}} ?
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName">
<option ng-repeat="item in names" ng-value="{{item}}">{{item.a }}</option>
</select>
<p>{{selectedName}}</p>   <!-- its a json stracture but -->
<p>{{selectedName.a}}</p>  <!-- behave like an object?!?!? -->
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
    {"a":"Emil1", "b":"Tobias1", "c":"Linus1"},
    {"a":"Emil2", "b":"Tobias2", "c":"Linus2"},
    {"a":"Emil3", "b":"Tobias3", "c":"Linus3"}
    ];
});
</script>

<p>This example shows how to fill a dropdown list using the ng-options directive.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName">
<option ng-repeat="item in names" value="{{item}}">{{item.a }}</option>
</select>
<p>{{selectedName}}</p> 
<p>{{selectedName.a}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
    {"a":"Emil1", "b":"Tobias1", "c":"Linus1"},
    {"a":"Emil2", "b":"Tobias2", "c":"Linus2"},
    {"a":"Emil3", "b":"Tobias3", "c":"Linus3"}
    ];
});
</script>

<p>This example shows how to fill a dropdown list using the ng-options directive.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why? Because `value` can only  be string so there is no object to have a property `a`. Why are you avoiding using `ng-options`?

Comment: when using ng-option the option value is an Object:id but I am trying to figure outhow using ng-value with json format convert to object.

Comment: Can make `ng-options` pass whatever you need to `ng-model`. Really not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: when using ng-option the option value is an Object:id but I am trying to figure out why using ng-value with json format convert to object.

Comment: on snippet 1 {{selectedName}} is a json! but {{selectedName.a}} is displaying like object behave. why?

Comment: It is not json ... json is a string data format and `$scope.names` is an array of objects

Comment: Great, So, even if I inspect the value of the option elements and I see json format == string , not object, it is an object?